# Transferring SFTP files from one remote server(linux) to another remote server(linux) using python

Tags: python-3.x, linux, sftp, remote-server

I want to download sftp files from server A and save it in server B using python. Both the servers are linux machines. I tried sftp.get(), but that's only between server and local machine. So far I have not seen any solution online. Is it possible to move the files between two servers? Please help

Comment: See the very first example on the documentation: https://pypi.org/project/pysftp/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Python developer, but I know how sftp works, and I don't think you can do what you are trying to do. The best way I can think is to do a sftp.get() to download the file from Server A to your local machine, and then an sftp.put() to upload it to server B